# Saving dynamically generated html attributes in a database (Asp.Net, Jquery)

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, hiddenfield

I am working on a self design dashboard page. Users drag&drop custom sized boxes in a div element and place some data inside boxes. Once they finish, I would like to save the certain attributes of these boxes in a db, instead of saving whole html code.

```
<div id="widget0" class="box span2">
    <div class="box-header well" style="padding-left: 3px;" data-original-title="">
        <div style="float:left">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-narrow-left btn-round"><i class=" icon-chevron-left"></i></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-extend-down btn-round"><i class=" icon-chevron-down"></i></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-narrow-up btn-round"><i class=" icon-chevron-up"></i></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-extend-right btn-round"><i class=" icon-chevron-right"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div style="float: right !important; margin-right: -15px;">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-close btn-round"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-content">
        <div id="boxContent0" style="width:100%;height:250px;border-collapse:collapse;" class="ui-droppable">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Above is a sample html code of my box. I'll just save div id, class and contents.

What I've done so far is, I saved required values in an asphiddenfield on a button click event in this format:

```
"2|widget0,span4,content1,content2|widget1,span3,0,0"
```

I did this by handling form submit event using jquery, triggered by asp button click. But the db write operations required in my server button click function didn't work. I think this is because I handled the form submit event before `btnSaveDashboard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` function handles and submit the form from jquery..

What I would like to do is, when user click on "save dashboard" button, before redirecting to the dashboard view page, to save these values in my db then redirect.

I just couldn't find a way how to do this with **one button click**;

- get the required html values
- save them in a hidden field or somewhere else reachable like viewstate
- save these values in my database

I can more provide more details in case needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Button's `OnClientClick` client side event to populate the HiddenField with the values you need before the Postback occurs.

If you accomplish that, you should have the values you want on the Button's `OnClick` server side event. You should be able to do whatever you want with them at this point.